# How to get total as a separate total Column in sql

Tags: sql, sum

I am trying to get Total_Paid column

```
Product     Timestamp   Paid                  Total_Paid
A             201801    12                     36
A             201802    11                     36
A             201803    13                     36
B             201801    10                     45
B             201802    15                     45
B             201803    20                     45
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a window function. For example:

```
select
  *,
  sum(paid) over(partition by product) as total_paid
from t
```